# What does it mean for a pdf to have this property?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> What does it mean for a probability density function $f(x)$ to have the following property?
>   $$1+\int_{x=0}^{\infty}x^2 \left(\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}-f''(x)\right)dx>0$$

I have tried a lot to simplify this condition and see what it means (in terms of moments of $f(x)$, etc), but no luck yet. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Might that be related to the [second derivative of the log](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453841/the-derivatives-of-the-logarithm-of-a-moment-generating-function) of mgf of $X$ at $t=0$ being equal to the variance of $X$?

Answer (score 2):

That can be written as
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^2 \cdot\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(f(x))\cdot f(x)\,dx < 1 $$
that is a constraint that depends on minimizing a [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://benmoran.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/kullback-leibler-divergence-asymmetry/).
It essentially gives that your distribution has to be close to a normal distribution (in the KL sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please clarify more, how it is related to KL divergence? between $f(x)$ and probably a normal distribution?

Comment: @Su20200: exactly that: we are computing the error of the "best normal distribution fit".

Comment: But, I don't see how it is  KL divergence  between f(x)f(x) and probably a normal distribution, given the second derivative of the log.

Comment: @Su20200: solve the following problem first: given a PDF $f(x)$, find the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ that minimizes the KL divergence. Our inequality tells us that the optimal approximation in the previous sense is not a terrible match in terms of high moments.

Comment: The second derivative appears as a by-product of the minimization process, for short.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time to answer it. Can you write down the steps?

Comment: Might that be related to the [second derivative of the log](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453841/the-derivatives-of-the-logarithm-of-a-moment-generating-function) of mgf of $X$ at $t=0$ being equal to the variance of $X$?